# Parsing a time instant in python

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python. 
I have a timestamp of the format - 2016-12-04T21:16:31.265Z. It is of a type string. I want to know how can I parse the above timestamp in python.

I was looking through the datetime library, but seems like it accepts only floats. How do I get the time stamp parsed? I was trying to hunt for something like an equivalent of Instant (in java) for python?

Comment: "I was looking through the datetime library, but seems like it accepts only floats." Where or how did you get this impression?

Comment: ran a python script on my desktop and it produced errors. I guess I wasn't completely following the instructions 100%

Comment: try `import datetime; datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-12-04T21:16:31.265Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")`

Comment: possible dupe of [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import datetime
time_str = '2016-12-04T21:16:31.265Z'
time_stamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print(time_stamp)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html; (8.1.7. `strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior)

Answer (score -1):

To parse it according to your current timezone, using the format used by the Unix **date** command:

```
import re
from calendar import timegm
from datetime import datetime
from time import localtime, strptime, strftime

fmt = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
ts = "2016-12-04T21:16:31.265Z"
strftime(fmt, localtime(timegm(strptime(re.sub("\.\d+Z$", "GMT", ts), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z'))))
```

Comment: This a copy/paste dump from a project? Where is `sleep` used?

Comment: Yes, It's code that I used to parse the ISO-8601 dates included in the Docker Registry manifests.

Comment: I don't think I'd like to maintain a library of `time` and `datetime` modules that also requires regex on top.